# Can MS Word 2003 put footnotes at the end of paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, footnote

Is there a way to make Word 2003 put footnotes at the end of a paragraph, including when a following paragraph begins on the same page?

Comment: Footnotes go at the bottom of the page on which the note appears. Period. You might be able to make use of the Comment feature. This is true of all versions of Word.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an answer to my own question.)

## Yes, there is a way:

select the option to position footnotes "below text" rather than at "bottom of page", and then insert a continuous section break at the end of the paragraph. Make sure you insert the break immediately after the whole of the paragraph, so if your footnote reference is the last thing in the paragraph you need to put the break after that.

This is kludgy but it does the job.

Comment: This will add an incredible amount of complexity/overhead to a document because section breaks carry a bunch of formatting.